# С++ аварийный выход из конструктора

Tags: c++, исключения, конструктор

Можно ли во время создания объекта, при сбое в конструкторе завершить его без создания объекта и оповестить об этом программу?

```
serialPort::serialPort(LPSTR serialName)
{
    HANDLE  serialDesc;

    // COM openning
        serialDesc = CreateFile(serialName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
        if (serialDesc == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
             // сделать что-то, что бы объект не создавался и оповестить программу
        }
}
```

Мне в голову приходят только передача указателя на внешнюю структуру с последующей проверкой, или содержать дополнительную переменную в классе, которую так же придется проверять извне.
Еще прочитал про `try-throw-catch`, но не могу найти явную информацию как он работает в конструкторе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще-то генерация исключения в конструкторе и означает, что объект не создан...

Само собой, все действия по очистке уже сделанного в конструкторе вы должны выполнить самостоятельно.

Comment: Т.Е: если происходит исключение (throw), то объект не создается?
Но если я уже успешно открыл несколько файлов в конструкторе, я обязан их закрыть в ручную, иначе они будут считаться открытыми, а их дескрипторы утеряны?

Comment: Да, вы должны выполнить такую очистку самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо. Имеется ли какой то стандартный способ оповестить программу создающую объект, что он не создан?

Comment: Да, это исключение. `throw` то, что вы хотите. Вот взгляните - https://ideone.com/9sqs6y Как видите, даже при создании через `new` память не выделена.

Comment: Обратите внимание - деструктор того объекта, который БЫЛ СОЗДАН ПОЛНОСТЬЮ! Я специально один объект создал, чтоб вы увидели, что созданный корректно уничтожится, а недосозданный - нет: объекта нет, нет и деструктора!

Comment: Да, увидел. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

> я обязан их закрыть в ручную, иначе они будут считаться открытыми, а
>   их дескрипторы утеряны?

закрывать обязательно нужно, так как во первых будет потеря ресурсов - файловых дескрипторов + памяти. Если ваша программа работает 24х7х365, то если эти объекты создаются постоянно, то ваша программа может аварийно завершиться.

Вопрос как? Если вы сгенерируете исключение в конструкторе, а файл - член этого класса?

Стандартный подход 
1) в конструкторе  не делать инициализую переменных (например просто их нулить) а делать это в отдельном методе, например init, которое может сгенерировать исключение, которое может быть обработано сверху.В этом подходе, у вас будет вызван деструктор, который будет освобождать ресурсы
2) Использовать наследование
3) Использовать умные указатели для членов класса, тут все понятно

Пример 1 решения

```
class Foo {
    FILE* f;
public:
    Foo() {
        f = 0;
    }
    virtual ~Foo() {
        if ( 0 != f)
            fclose(f);
    }

    bool init() {
        f = fopen("file.txt", "+rw");
        if ( !f ) {
            throw 1;
        }

        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        size_t fileSize = ftell(f);
        if (fileSize < 100)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
};

int main() {

    {
        Foo f;
        try {
            f.init();
        }
        catch (int& e) {
            // Обработка исключения,  о ресурсах не беспокоимся, деструктор
            // класса Foo все сделает 
        }
    }
}
```

Второй способ основан на том, чтобы поместить f в базовый класс и и там освобождать ресурсы ( при исключении в конструкторе порожденного класса, вызовется  и деструктор базового)

Пример 2 Решения
Перенесем метод инит в конструктор порожденного класса

```
class Foo {
    FILE* f;

public:
    Foo() {
        f = 0;
    }
    virtual ~Foo() {
        if ( 0 != f)
            fclose(f);
    }
};

class Delivery: public Foo {
    bool fileIsBig;
public:
    Delivery(const char* fileName) {
        fileIsBig = true;
        f = fopen(fileName, "+rw");
        if ( !f ) {
            throw 1;
        }

        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        size_t fileSize = ftell(f);
        if (fileSize < 100)
            fileIsBig = false;
    }

    virtual ~Delivery() {
    }
};

int main() {
    try {
        Delivery d("myfile");
    }
    catch (int& e) {
        // Обработка исключения из конструктора, ресурсы будут освобождены
    }
}
```